# Application crashes while fetching data from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an application in which I am converting `UIImage` to `NSData` an further `NSData` to `Base64String` using this https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64 class....but the App crashes When I want to fetch the converted string to the other class.
It gives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS error`...
Is it possible that `NSString` can't handle such big strings or is there any other issue?

Here is my code....

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"earring_hoops_small.jpg"];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1f);
    NSData *data2 = data;
    NSLog(@"BaseString=%@",data2);
    [Base64 initialize];
    strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
    NSLog(@"BaseString=%@",strEncoded);
```

and It gives exception while....

```
myString = strEncoded;
```

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: NSString can handle it because those are [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on NSData and NSString.

Comment: In addition to adding your actual code as mentioned previously, also post the crash report! We can't possibly imagine what your code might possibly look like, and the exception reason isn't enough to understand the crash itself either.

Comment: @thavasidurai Here is the code